# Creating constant values

Tags: c

Im trying to get all the genres from my context and display them.

This what I get when I run the program:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyBooks.Models.BookEntity'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Edit

```
return View(new BooksEdit
{
    BookName = book.BookName,

    Genre = context.Genre.Select(b => new GenreList
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        //This causes the error
        yesGenre = book.Genres.Contains(b),
        BookName = b.Name
    }).ToList()
});
```

Book

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string BookName{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<GEnre> Genres{ get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
    }
}
```

Genre

```
public class Genre
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string GEnreName{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Book> Books{ get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel

```
public class GenreList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool yesGenre{ get; set; }
    public string GenreName{ get; set; }
}

public class BookEdit
{

    public IList<GenreList> Genres{ get; set; } 

    public string BookName{ get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Exactly _"Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"_ You can't use custom classes, you must use primitive types or lists of primitive types

Comment: I rolled back your revision in which you erased everything but the first sentence. The code is the relevant part, also after a question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute the db.Roles query first, using **ToList()** and your code should work:

```
Roles = db.Roles.ToList().Select(r => new RoleCheckbox
{
    Id = r.Id,
    //This should work now
    IsChecked = user.Roles.Contains(r),
    Name = r.Name
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the issue is that the `user.Roles` is a different type than the `db.Roles`. As such one cannot possibly contain the other.

Try rewriting that as this:

```
return View(new UsersEdit
{
    Username = user.Username,
    Email = user.Email,

    Roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new RoleCheckbox
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        //This should no longer cause an issue.
        IsChecked = user.Roles.Any(role => role.Id == r.Id),
        Name = r.Name
    }).ToList()
});
```

With `Linq` you can use `.Any` and pass a predicate that will evaluate in a similar fashion to the `.Contains` you were looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that LINQ to Entities does not support `Contains` with class (`RoleEntity` in your case).

What you need to do is to create a list of "primitive types", in your case list of `int` containing role `Id`s.

```
var userRoleIds = user.Roles.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
```

and then use it as follows

```
IsChecked = userRoleIds.Contains(r.Id),
```